# What is the expectation? $E\left[\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{X_n}\right]$?

Tags: probability, expectation

i'm just trying to figure this out.

$$P(X_n = 1) = p \mbox{ and } P(X_n =−1)=q \\
\mbox{for each }n∈N(p,q∈(0,1),p+q=1,p>q)$$

what is
$$
E\left[\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{X_n}\right]
$$

This is part of a bigger martingale question, it is just this part I do not understand, the expectation given was $(p+q)$ which equal to 1. How do I do this part?

Thanks for your help. (psttt : this is also my first question on stackexchange ;))

Comment: **Hint**: $P_{X_n}$ is a discrete distribution. If you're familiar with Dirac delta notation, $$dP_{X_n}(x)=p\delta(x-1)+q\delta(x+1)$$

Comment: By definition, $$E\left[\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{X_n}\right]=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{1}P(X_n=1)+\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{-1}P(X_n=-1)$$ hence there is a mistake in the statement of the exercise...

Comment: thanks for your help, the question given to me was wrong it should be $\frac{q}{p}$ i will notify my lecturer immediately and edit the question thanks for your help !

Comment: With Did's help, you should be able to resolve this part of your question: Replace $(p/q)$ in his comment by $(q/p)$, wherever it appears, and rewrite $P(X_n = \pm 1)$ in terms of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: yeah i solved it ! should i answer my own question? I'm still new at this

Comment: Yes you should, definitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Did:

$E[(\frac{q}{p})^{X_n}]=(\frac{q}{p})^1P(X_n‌=1)+(\frac{q}{p})^{−1}P(X_n=−1)=\frac{q}{p}p+\frac{p}{q}q=p+q=1$